# Call a service from Tomcat in Servicemix 4.3

Tags: web-services, tomcat, apache-servicemix

I have a webservice running on Tomcat 6 in this address http://localhost8080/testservice, now i want to deploy it to Servicemix 4.3
Anyone knows a simple tutorial, on how to call this webservice from Servicemix 4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are a few links to help you get started with this...

first, a guide to creating/deploying/testing a web service in Servicemix and a link to an example that ships with servicemix...

http://servicemix.apache.org/4-beginner-web-services-with-servicemix-and-cxf.html

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/smx3/trunk/samples/wsdl-first/README.txt

next, here is a guide to generating a cxf code-first OSGI bundle

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployCxf-Running.html

finally, you can also use Apache Camel to interface with web services...

http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html

http://camel.apache.org/how-to-run-camel-in-a-osgi-container.html